# What is the best way to export all Nestuite data using API

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to know is there any way to create a dynamic restlet that includes all the data and fields. This restlet should be able to get data from a newly created field also without modifying the restlet code.

```
getAllfields()
```

this can be used to get all the fields in a record, but how to use this to get all the data from a record if after restlet is made someone adds a new cuscol field in transaction line item. Also what about custom records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the record and use JSON.stringify to send it over. This would work on custom records as well.

Comment: ya that is the easiest way .. but i want to know is there any other way apart from this ?